# How to use ReaderT to transform Happstack's ServerPart Response?

Tags: haskell

This is the first time I'm playing with Monad Transformers. This is a simple happstack app.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Happstack.Lite 
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L

main :: IO ()
main = do
    serve Nothing hello 

hello :: ServerPart Response
hello = do
    ok $ toResponse ("Hello" :: L.ByteString)
```

I would like to be able to change hello so it can read some global config data using `ReaderT`. Let's just say the config is a string to keep it simple

```
type NewMonad = ReaderT L.ByteString (ServerPartT IO) 
runNewMonad :: NewMonad a -> L.ByteString -> ServerPart a
runNewMonad k c = runReaderT k c
```

How do I change hello so it can use `ask`? I'm not sure what the type would be. `NewMonad Response` isn't quite right, because `ok` returns a `ServerPart Response`.

How do I change main so that `serve` works? It expects a `ServerPart Response`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, `NewMonad Response` is the correct type for `hello`; you just need to use [`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html) to transform an action in the underlying monad to one in the transformer. For example:

```
hello :: NewMonad Response
hello = do
    foo <- ask
    lift . ok $ toResponse foo
```

In general,

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

i.e., if you have a monadic action, then you turn it into an action in any monad transformer over that monad. This is the definition of a monad transformer: it can transform over any monad, and embed actions of that monad.

It seems that restricting all the monadic actions to one specific monad — rather than using typeclasses to work in any appropriate monad — is one of the simplifications happstack-lite uses compared to the full Happstack, which has [this type for `ok`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/happstack-server/latest/doc/html/Happstack-Server-Response.html#v%3aok):

```
ok :: (FilterMonad Response m) => a -> m a
```

With this type, assuming appropriate instances are declared for the standard transformers, you could just use `ok` directly in `MyMonad`.

As for `main`, you need to eliminate the `ReaderT` layer, leading a a `ServerPart Response` that you can pass to `serve`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    serve Nothing $ runNewMonad hello ("Hello" :: L.ByteString)
```

(This would cause problems if you were using a monad carrying state that you wanted to change over the course of many requests, since `serve`'s type is too restrictive to support such state threading (without manually encoding it with `IORef`s or similar); possibly the unrestricted Happstack has the ability to do this, but it'd likely be very brittle anyway, as you shouldn't really be relying on the order requests are processed in like that.)

Comment: Thanks! Trying the second approach I get this error: No instance for (Happstack.Server.Internal.Monads.FilterMonad Response (ReaderT L.ByteString (ServerPartT IO)))
      arising from a use of `ok'

Comment: happstack-server 6.5.3's documentation [lists a `FilterMonad` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/happstack-server/6.5.3/doc/html/Happstack-Server-Internal-Monads.html#t:FilterMonad) for `ReaderT`; perhaps you're using an older version? It seems the instances were added [four days ago](http://happstack.blogspot.com/2012/01/ann-happstack-server-651.html).

Comment: That was it. Now I get it to compile, but not run :( Happstack-server-6.5.3 depends on libcryptopp and I'm having trouble linking it on osx, but that's probably better in another question.